# Inverse Gramian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Show that inverse Gramian matrix is Gramian matrix

Here is my idea. 
$\Gamma ^ {-1} = \frac{A}{|\Gamma|}$, where A is transposed matrix of cofactors (not sure about the term, correct me please), |Г| is the Gramian determinant, |Г| > 0. We need to show that corner minors in A satisfy the Sylvester's criteria. But on this step I am stuck.

Comment: In other words show that the inverse of a symmetric matrix is symmetric?

Comment: Gramian matrix is positively-semidefinite and symmetric. Showing that the inverse matrix of symmetric matrix is symmetric matrix is not complicated. But the other property is not obvious for me.

Comment: I see. (some more characters)

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing the eigenvalue decomposition of the original Gramian matrix, and assume it is positive definite. When you take the inverse of this matrix, it corresponds to inverting the eigenvalues with the same eigenvectors. Because the original eigenvalues were positive, the inverse eigenvalues are still positive and so the inverse Gramian is still positive definite. Because every positive definite matrix corresponds to the Gramian for some set of vectors, this inverse Gramian is a Gramian matrix.